# Why is a question duplicated when the other question has nothing to do with the first? Does that mean that no answer is wanted to be given?

Tags: discussion

I typed a question, and it was added as a duplicate, but there is no reference to the issues in the answer which is what is assigned as duplicate, as it doesn't address the issue at all.  It is about two totally different things, and to hide it as a duplicate means that the issue is not being looked into.  Who do I contact to discuss this in more detail, so that somebody can actually look at it without "writing" it off?

Comment: Questions are generally marked as duplicate if few of us think it is actually a duplicate. If the question that your has been marked as duplicate of doesn't answer your question, edit your question to clarify what your asking or why the answers in the other post aren't applicable. This usually happens when a question isn't clearly formulated or lacking details.

Comment: It's a bit tough to really answer without know which question(s) you're referring to. Could you link to them so that we can answer more concretely?